# Force on a magnetic dipole falling through a copper tube

Tags: electromagnetism, special-relativity

In [this](http://www.msc.univ-paris-diderot.fr/~phyexp/uploads/LaimantParesseux/Tube-Aimant2.pdf) paper, the authors have calculated the force on the tube, and stated that the magnitude of force on the magnet is same due to Newton's third law.

However, the third law is not valid under the special theory of relativity. In this case, are the forces still equal and opposite in magnitude due to some deeper reason? Is the net momentum carried by the fields is zero in this case?

Or is it just a low speed approximation? In electromagnetism, low speed approximations are not always valid (then magnetic force due to slowly moving charges would not arise)

In case it is a low speed approximation, how to find the force of the magnet on from an inertial frame where the tube is stationary?

Comment: Does the question have anything to do with the paper specifically, or are you just asking if Newton's third law holds under special relativity?

Comment: @Doug I have read that Newton's third law is not valid under special relativity. So, I am asking whether the result (force on the magnet) in the paper is exact, and if not, then how to derive it, given that the force in the copper tube has already been found

Comment: Why are you invoking special relativity? All the velocities needed here are very small compared to c

Comment: Triatticus is correct, also see https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/240053/griffiths-argument-that-newtons-third-law-is-invalid-in-special-relativity

Comment: Are not some momentum stored in the field? I am asking how to find the relativistic exact force, under dipole approximation of magnet

Comment: @Triatticus in electromagnetism, the effect of small speeds is not negligible.